# How to set chrome app size relative to the screen

Tags: background, size, google-chrome-app

Why is my code not working? I am trying to set the size of my app to 80% of the screen as I want it to fit on any monitor, if there is a better way I would like to know about it.

`background.js`:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': window.screen.availWidth*0.8, // *0.8 is not working
            'height': window.screen.availHeight*0.8
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the number must be rounded since many decimals cannot be handled:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': Math.round(window.screen.availWidth*0.8),
            'height': Math.round(window.screen.availHeight*0.8)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: screen.availWidth is not the actual screen width but the width without borders toolbars by the os etc. For the actual width use screen.width